# Is there a way to format time without Colons (:) using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I want to format "08:05:33" time (hours:minutes:seconds) into "080533" (without the colon). I only need the time, date is not needed.

Is there a way to do that using Moment.js?

I have used

```
let time = "08:05:33";
let value = moment(time).format('hhmmss');
```

I ended up with "Invalid date".

Comment: Well have you tried doing it? Did you read the [documentation about formatting time in Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) and give it a try? Please show your attempt

Comment: Why do you want to use Moment for a simple JS replace? Assuming the time is just a string

Comment: @Varuni Punchihewa your time input is not valid. Enter a valid time to instantiate moment() time

Comment: If your input is in that format, why do you even need moment to get the output? Just follow the answer by @C14L

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a

```
"08:05:33".replaceAll(":", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just format the moment object with `'hhmmss'`

```js
let now = moment().format('hhmmss');
console.log(now)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answering, I was able to find a solution.

Yes, you can do it as @C14L has suggested, but in this case, I particularly want to use Moment.js

I was able to solve the issue with the following code.

```js
let time = "08:05:33";
let value = moment(time, 'HH:mm:ss').format('HHmmss');

console.log(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```